# HTML5 hidden attribute not compatible with Bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I was refactoring some code and decided to change the usual `style="display:none"` to use the HTML5 `hidden` attribute, in order to hide a button. Only to find that it is not compatible with bootstrap's `btn` class. That said, I will keep using the style display attribute but I wonder if this is a bug that should be reported or simply a feature that everyone should be aware of.

The corresponding jsfiddle can be found [here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/56ax4phv/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HTML5 specification already warns developers about this:

> **Note:** Because this attribute is typically implemented using CSS, it's also possible to override it using CSS. **For instance, a rule that applies 'display: block' to all elements will cancel the effects of the hidden attribute.** Authors therefore have to take care when writing their style sheets to make sure that the attribute is still styled as expected.
>
> — [The HTML5 Specification - 7.1 The `hidden` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#the-hidden-attribute)

The problem you're having is that Bootstrap's `.btn` selector specifically defines `display: inline-block`, which overrides the `hidden` attribute's `display: none`.

This means that specificity is going to be an issue. This is a rare case of where `!important` may be desirable. I'd personally implement the following style rule:

```css
[hidden] {
  display: none !important;
}
```

This ensures that all elements with a `hidden` attribute will be set to not display, regardless of specificity. This is doubly good in that this will make the `hidden` attribute effective on any browser which supports the `[att]` selector notation (which is any browser which supports CSS2).

---

[Working JSFiddle demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/56ax4phv/1/).

Comment: Thanks James, just the kind of answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this to your css:

```
*[hidden] { display: none !important; }
```

for example; https://fiddle.jshell.net/bh8h5tya/

Comment: May need to add !important to ensure it always applies correctly.

Comment: If I could I would downvote this :). It is not what I asked, I knew how to work around it, I just wanted a good explanation for everybody to understand what is happening.

Comment: @rll I'm sorry I have failed you master. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not hidden because bootstrap applies `display: inline-block` on the class `.btn`

Bootstrap provides the following `.hidden` class that you can use to show/hide elements. Try using that.

```
.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}
```